# Does restoring a local backup using iTunes enable activation lock?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, apple-id, activation-lock

Let's say I have an Apple ID that's been disabled/locked for security reasons.

- This account is linked to my iPhone and in order to remove it or to simply disable find my iPhone, I have to answer the security questions on the account which I don't remember anymore. So basically the account is glued to the device with FMI enabled.
- So then I get a new phone and restore a local iTunes backup that I made of the old phone with the account issue on to the new phone.

FMI shows as enabled on the new phone's settings but I am not sure it's actually enabled. IMEI checker sites such as imeipro show that it's disabled but I want to get your opinion on the matter. I want to format the new phone and worry it too will become activation locked.

Does restoring a local backup using iTunes enable activation lock?

Comment: I tried to make this one question per question - @ me in comments if I somehow missed your main point. Are there three physical phones in play here or just two. Giving them clear names "Alice" "Bob" "Carlos" etc... would reduce any chance we misunderstand each other.

Comment: Only two phones, an old and a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, restoring a backup from a device that is locked doesn't lock the new device - devices are locked to accounts, not files in the backup.

Each device can be tied to find my and data can move between accounts without changing the status of iCloud / Activation / MDM or other locks.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer, so does that mean that it's safe for me to format the new iPhone?

Comment: It’s never “safe” to format in that it can always go wrong @AhmedK. But your situation isn’t any more concerning than a normal erase. You appear to have the best backup you can given the situation. The phone that was activation locked will still be locked, the ones not locked will remain not locked. You will be able to enroll any phone into lock when you have control over the credentials and an not-already-locked iPhone.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thanks @bmike